# How do I generate a glTF file and then include it in a link and open it in AR using Android Scene Viewer?

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality

I am trying to generate a glTF file from a custom 3D glTF configurator I am building. The file is being generated and I can download it without a problem if I use `link.href = URL.createObjectURL( blob );` and `link.download = filename;` in the `save(blob)` function. However, what I am trying to do is to first generate the glTF file and then concatenate it in the `link.href` so instead of just downloading the glTF file to be able to open it in AR using Google Scene Viewer on an Android mobile device. Unfortunately when I am calling the `exportGLTF()` function the browser crashes! Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

```
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.style.display = 'none';

  function exportGLTF() {
    var gltfExporter = new GLTFExporter();

    gltfExporter.parse(
      scene,
      function (result) {
        var output = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
        saveString(output, 'scene.gltf');
      },
      options
    );
  }

  function saveString(text, filename) {
    save(new Blob([text], { type: 'application/json' }), filename);
  }

  function save(blob) {
    link.href =
      'intent://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer/1.1?file=' +
      URL.createObjectURL(blob) +
      '&mode=ar_only#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.google.ar.core;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end';
    link.click();
  }
```